# The constructor Time_Class_sub(int, int, int) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor

I am not sure why I have been told the The constructor `Time_Class_sub(int, int, int)` is undefined. The int 4,5,6 are already stated in the parentheses.

This is the main class:

```
public class Time_Class_main {  
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Time_Class_sub linktosub = new Time_Class_sub(4, 5, 6);

        //linktosub.settime(3, 4, 65);

        System.out.println(linktosub.tomilitary());
    }
}
```

This is the subsidiary class:

```
public class Time_Class_sub {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public void Time_Class_sub(int h, int m, int s){
        //if the condition is met, assign hour = h. If not, h = 0
        hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minute = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        second = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
    }

    public String tomilitary () {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, `Time_Class_sub(int h, int m, int s)` is a class? looks more like a function to me. In order to be a class, you have to make it a class called `Time_Class_sub` and then have a function in it called `public Time_Class_sub(int h, int m, int s)` (without the void)

Answer (score 1):

Constructors of a class do not have a return type - not even void. In your case, you specified a normal instance method that by accident has the same name as the class (remember, there's effectively three different namespaces for fields, type names and method names).

Just remove the `void` and you're set.

Also, please follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - your class name should be `TimeClassSub`.

Edit: If this is production code and not just an assignment, please for the sake of everything that is holy read [this](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Comment: Thanks. It works after I removed [code] void [/code].
But why constructor cannot be used in method with void which is not meant to return any value in contrast to method like public String or public int which has to have a return value? 
Also, in order to let constructor to work, don't we are required to name the method same as the class?

Comment: The constructor in a sense already has a value - `this`, the object that is being constructed. There is no sense to returning anything else, and there is no sense in specifying a return type, because we already know it. The constructor is not a method that you can call in your code. Also, yes, the constructor needs to have the same name as your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class Time_Class_sub
{
  private int hour {get; set;}
  private int minute {get; set;}
  private int second {get; set;}

  public Time_Class_sub(int h, int m, int s)
  {
    //if the condition is met, assign hour = h. If not, h = 0
    hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
    minute = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
    second = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
  }

  public string tomilitary () {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
  }
}
```

also you might consider to implement a function called

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
```

if you are programming in c# (please add your programming language as a tag)

Comment: Java tag is added. Could you help to explain your solution? Thanks.

Comment: As I wrote, my solution is in C#, but it should be the same in Java. Override is possible in Java, too. I however do not know your knowledge and I could tell a lot on what and how this happens. Maybe best would be, to search it up yourself, see https://www.google.de/#q=java+override+tostring